# How to get id inside of event handling function with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

```
$('#check1,#check2').click(function() {

});
```

Live above,how to tell if "check1" or "check2" is clicked ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On event handler functions, the context (the [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/this_Operator) keyword) within the function, represents the HTML Element that triggered the event.

You can:

```
$('#check1,#check2').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id'); // or simply this.id
});
```

Comment: Sure, since `this` is the HTMLElement

Answer (score 1):

Inside your function you can get the ID of the element and compare..

```
if($(this).attr("id") == "check1") ...
```